# What is the demonym for people from Gallifrey?

Tags: doctor-who

I am looking for the demonym that applies to the citizens of Gallifrey.

References are welcomed.

Comment: I am here to officially state that the demonym is in fact _Gallifreyan_.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Boy, would your face be red if it turned out to be something else...

Comment: Actually, it's Gallifried Chickens. Or some people would say Gallifornians. Others have moved on from Imperial measurements and refer to them as Literifreyans.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The BBC released an [official script](http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/writersroom/scripts/DW9-EP12-Hell-Bent.pdf) for the episode *[Hell Bent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell_Bent_(Doctor_Who))*.

It features both this scene description

> EXT. **GALLIFREYAN DESERT/CITY** - DAY 3
> The horizon, almost lost in the heat shimmer.

and this dialogue

> **ASHILDR** (cont’d): *Tell me, Doctor, I’ve always wanted to know - you’re a Time Lord, you’re **a high born Gallifreyan**. Why do you spend so much time on Earth?*

---

Additionally, the term is used (repeatedly) on the BBC's website

> The Doctor links K9 to the Matrix in order to determine their point of
> origin. His plan is to place a time loop around their home planet, but
> he must avoid arousing their suspicions - hence his erratic behaviour.
> He banishes Leela to the wastelands of outer Gallifrey for fear that
> she might unintentionally jeopardise his plans. There she meets a
> group of Gallifreyan outsiders, and together they organise an attack
> on the Capitol to fight off the invaders.
>
> <sub><sup>[Classic Series: The Invasion of Time](http://www.bbc.co.uk/doctorwho/classic/episodeguide/invasiontime/detail.shtml)</sup></sub>

and in the official [Doctor Who Annual (2009)](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Who_The_Official_Annual_2009)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

As used elsewhere on [this website](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50616/time-lords-and-gallifreyans-whats-the-difference), the demonym for inhabitants of Gallifrey is *Gallifreyan* (which is also the word for the language, similar to some demonyms on Earth).

https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Gallifreyan

The first instance of the use of the term Gallifreyan was in the script for the unfinished and unaired Tom Baker episode Shada. There are multiple uses of the word in the episode to refer to the language, but it is also used in reference to the people by Chronotis.

> CHRONOTIS: I was, I am, I will be, Professor Chronotis. Oh dear. We
>   Gallifreyans have never managed to come up with a satisfactory form of
>   grammar to cover these situations.

http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/17-6.htm

Prior to that, the people of Gallifrey had only been referred to in the context of Time Lords.

The BBC don't have a copy of the script on their website (among many, many others). Copies of the original script are up for sale.

Comment: I'm not a fan of fan-written wiki articles. Can you offer any *primary* sources?

Comment: @Valorum does chakoteya.net meet your criteria? What about stage directions (as opposed to dialogue) on there?

Comment: @OrangeDog - Nope. Those are fan-written transcripts. Try the BBC pages.

Comment: @Valorum what if I do a search on there, and pretend I already went and checked that the dialogue was accurate?

Comment: https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/profiles/1VlQBRKSxGMnSWFmPCPPtmV/the-president for example

Comment: @GeoffAtkins as Shada was technically never made you might want to use dialogue from *The Two Doctors* and/or *Hell Bent*

Comment: @OrangeDog, Shada was the first use of the word in a Doctor Who script in reference to the people. They filmed a lot of the episode, released it as an audiobook, and the filmed segments were released on video with Tom Baker providing narration for the missing sections.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins I am aware, but it is of a lower "canonicity" than the broadcast episodes I suggested (one from old, one from new).

Comment: @OrangeDog - Canonicity in Doctor Who? You are aware of Wibbly-Wobbly Timey-Wimey, right?